# AWS Lambda Create Function Role Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

Going through some tutorials on AWS Lambda Functions. I keep receiving the error, "It seems there was an error during your role template creation, please double check if the role name is already existing and try again."

I've tried many different scenarios, new roles, existing roles, editing the roles in IAM, give more access and then trying them. I tried creating a lambda function "Authored from Scratch" and "Blueprints". I also logged into my root account to see if my user account had an issue.

Frustrated... can't create anything in Lambda because I receive this error 100% of the time.

[AWS Lambda Error Blueprint Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gtln.png)
[AWS Lambda Error Scratch New Role Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRp3M.png)

Comment: You specified that you tried using existing roles. So even in that case do you get the same probelm

Comment: I also tried Create a New Role over and over. Have you ever created a Lambda Function?

Comment: I've created lots of Lambda functions. I also tried to create it the exact way as your screenshot and for me it succeeds

Comment: So just to ask my question again.. do you get the exact same error even when you try to use an existing role

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I encountered this and it drove me nuts. In the end I wondered if the GUI was giving me incorrect info, and the role was in fact NOT 'already existing'. I went off and did something else for a couple of minutes, and when I came back everything worked fine with no problems. I suspect it's an AWS console bug.

Comment: Yea, I learned a lot in the lab, so I just killed all of the resources and moved on. :)

Comment: A year later and I now run into this issue as well. Going to IAM I do not see all these "failed" roles. But I do see them listed in the lambda creation screen. To get around it I chose an already created "role". Seems to be an AWS bug/issue that will probably go away later today.

Answer (score 5):

This is still an issue in 2020!

I choose an existing role or try to create a new one, and I get the `An error occured during the creation of your role template. Double-check whether the role name already exists and try again.` no matter what I choose.

The only option is to wait for 10 minutes and try again.

Comment: It's been 15 minutes already. Still getting this! This is so frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Jan 26,2021 - Still an issue .So this is essentially a role based issue and definitely seems to be a bug in the lambda console. What worked for me is to first go to the IAM console , create a role , attach a policy with 'AdministratorAccess',and in 'Trust Relationships' tab add 'lambda.amazonaws.com' as a trusted entity. After this , while creating a lambda function, use this existing role ( instead of creating a new one), and it it should work.

Comment: It's disappointing that trusted entity lambda.amazonaws.com needs to be given explicit permission, but it makes sense and this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

What a terrible bug!

I was trying to create Java 8 Lambda function with "Create a new role with basic Lambda permissions" and it took me 30 minutes to stop getting this error.

The only solution seems to be to wait.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue but after add condition in trust policy of role.

my working role trust policy was

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    }
  }
}
```

but when i add, condition for assume by specific resource like below, i don't know will it work or not and it give me error "It seems there was an error during your role template creation, please double check if the role name is already existing and try again." .

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1234567890:function:project-developers-*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

so after change like first one, it's work fine.